# VBA code to cut a row from one excel sheet to another based on if the date in the row has already past

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried using the following code to create a VBA to cut from one sheet to another based on if the date value in column K has already past but i keep getting a run-time error '1004' because of the last line 'destinationsheet'. Any help will be muchly appreciated. Here is the VBA code:

```
Sub MoveExpiredData()
Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
Dim destinationSheet As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim wb As Workbook


    'Set the workbook that contains the data

Set wb = Workbooks("Teds Test weekly Tracker.xlsx")

    'Set the worksheet that contains the data

Set currentSheet = wb.Sheets("1")

    'Set the worksheet that the expired data will be moved to

Set destinationSheet = wb.Sheets("3")

    'Find the last row in the current sheet

lastRow = currentSheet.Cells(currentSheet.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

    'Loop through each row in the sheet and check if the date has passed


For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1 ' Start from the last row and move up to avoid skipping rows
'Check if the cell in column K is in date format and not merged
If IsDate(currentSheet.Cells(i, "K").Value) And Not currentSheet.Cells(i, "K").MergeCells Then
If currentSheet.Cells(i, "K").Value \< Date Then 'Check if the date in column K has passed
currentSheet.Rows(i).Cut 'Cut the row
destinationSheet.Cells(destinationSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'Paste the row in the destination sheet
End If
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

I tried to add a underscore like i saw in the code here (https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/cut-copy-paste-with-macro/) but the visual basic did not take it

Comment: add a line `destinationSheet.Activate` before the line that's throwing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the below code for proper cut and paste

```
For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1 ' Start from the last row and move up to avoid skipping rows
'Check if the cell in column K is in date format and not merged
If IsDate(currentSheet.Cells(i, "K").Value) And Not currentSheet.Cells(i, "K").MergeCells Then

If currentSheet.Cells(i, "K").Value <= Date Then 'Check if the date in column K has passed

lastRow1 = destinationSheet.Cells(currentSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

currentSheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.Cut destinationSheet.Range("A" & lastRow1 + 1)
```